# Why does the Supreme Court of Canada's website translate "to" as "auprès de"?

Tags: traduction, prépositions, locutions, droit-et-justice

My first guess was simply *à*, *de*, or *pour*. [Trois diplômés accèdent aux prestigieux stages d’auxiliaires juridiques à la Cour Suprême du Canada - Faculté de droit - Université de Montréal](https://droit.umontreal.ca/faculte/communication/nouvelles/nouvelles/news/detail/News/trois-diplomes-accedent-aux-prestigieux-stages-dauxiliaires-juridiques-a-la-cour-supreme-du-canada/)

> #### Léa Boutrouille
>
> ##### Auxiliaire auprès de l’honorable [Richard Wagner](https://www.scc-csc.ca/judges-juges/bio-fra.aspx?id=richard-wagner), juge en chef

Namely, I would've written auxiliaire *à/de/pour*  l’honorable Richard Wagner.

English version of [Supreme Court of Canada - Law Clerks Program](https://www.scc-csc.ca/empl/lc-aj-eng.aspx)

> ### Law Clerks to the Judges of the Supreme Court of Canada
>
> Applications are invited for 36 positions of law clerks to the 9 judges of the Supreme Court of Canada. A pool of qualified candidates may be established and may be used to staff identical or similar positions.

Just click on the upper right corner for the other of Canada's official language!

> ### Auxiliaires juridiques auprès des juges de la Cour suprême du Canada
>
> Appel de candidatures pour 36 postes d’auxiliaire juridique auprès des neuf juges de la Cour suprême du Canada. Un bassin de personnes qualifiées pourrait être établi et pourrait être utilisé pour doter des postes identiques ou semblables.

*auprès de* is also used at [Trois diplômées de l'UQAM recrutées comme auxiliaires juridiques à la Cour suprême du Canada | Faculté de science politique et de droit | UQAM](https://fspd.uqam.ca/nouvelle/trois-diplomees-de-luqam-recrutees-comme-auxiliaires-juridiques-a-la-cour-supreme-du-canada/)

> À l’UQAM, ce processus débute par une sélection interne menée par un comité composé cette année du Doyen, **Me Hugo Cyr** (auxiliaire juridique auprès de l’honorable juge Ian Binnie en 1999-2000) et de deux nouveaux professeurs à la Faculté, **Me Gabriel-Arnaud Berthold** (auxiliaire juridique auprès de l’honorable juge Louis LeBel en 2013-2014) et **Me Guillaume Laganière** (auxiliaire juridique auprès de l’honorable juge en chef Beverley McLachlin en 2013-2014).

Answer (score 5):

First, the "locution prépositive" *auprès de* can be used for introducing a complement designating a person having official duties, or some institution or entity, and showcases, aside from location, this idea of an assignment and being accredited to be there (translated quickly from the *TLFi*, [*auprès (de)*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aupr%C3%A8s) I A 3. examples 32-25). Outside of this, *auprès de* is generally often about close and/or continuous proximity, and considering the duties of the [*auxiliaire juridique*](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=AUXILIAIRE%20JURIDIQUE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) and the very word [*auxiliaire*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/auxiliaire), that seems also fitting in this case. Then consider you might even find *près* without the preposition *de* with that sort of legal phrasing with the same meaning:

> — Dans la langue juridique et diplomatique : *L'ambassadeur de France
> AUPRÈS DU Saint-Siège* ([Ac. 2000](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9A3169)), ou, sans *de* :
>
> [...]
>
> Dans la langue juridique et diplomatique, *près* sans *de* remplace
> souvent *auprès de* : *Expert PRÈS le tribunal de...* — *Notre
> ambassadeur PRÈS le Saint-Siège* (MONTHERL., *Treizième César*, p. 49)
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>,
> amalgame des § 1046, 1073 ]

---

This is more legal/diplomacy related usage from what I can tell, not necessarily casual prepositional affinity, even though it's in line with the idea of close proximity which *auprès de* is all about. If it wasn't for this usage, I could see the preposition *de* or *pour* here like you suggested, but not *à* imho; I could see *à* with the noun or something like "rôle d'auxiliaire (à) "as opposed to the title (clerk/*auxiliaire*) per se, but I couldn't tell you why exactly, maybe some prepositional preference depending on whether it's a person or not.

Comment: n.b. When I read "Law Clerks to the Judges", as a learner of the English language I'm initially expecting "for" instead, for some reason or another, and I'm asking myself if it's maybe because you can say someone is "articling" *to* someone else; that topic can be explored elsewhere (ELU) but my point is this prepositional usage seems somewhat different than what I expected. So I kind of hear you, from the other side of things, so to speak.

Comment: The collocation in English is "a clerk to someone/position/office" in the same vein as "a secretary to sb.", probably to invoke a similar feeling to *auprès de* in French by emphasizing the office (of the judge) instead of the person.

Comment: @xngtng Thank you for your input, that was insightful and also validates some of my intuition about this. _Emphasizing the office (of the judge) instead of the person_, well put.