# Peut-on toujours traduire le mot «pool» dans le contexte d'un rassemblement d'éléments par «bassin»?

Tags: traduction, informatique, travail

Je dirige le développement d'un logiciel et nous sommes à réviser la terminologie utilisée dans l'application. Je cherche à traduire l'expression «pool» dans le contexte d'un lot de changements devant être regroupés pour être appliqués ensemble.

Le contexte où ce mot est utilisé en anglais dans notre application concerne le fait d'amasser un certain nombre de changements de prix devant être appliqués à une même date, plusieurs dates pouvant être définies selon la raison (date de fin de promotion, date de début de saison, etc). Il s'agit de créer des *pools* de changements.

Beaucoup d'exemples existent en anglais de ce mot pour signifier un groupe d'éléments de même nature comme dans la [question ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/47213/why-does-the-supreme-court-of-canadas-website-translate-to-as-aupr%C3%A8s-de) (note : la question n'est pas reliée à l'utilisation du mot pool) on affiche ceci:

> (...)  A pool of qualified candidates (...) qui est traduit par (...)
> Un bassin de personnes qualifiées (...)

Puis-je parler d'un bassin de changements à sélectionner?

**Mise à jour :** Nous avons décidé de ne pas aller avec «pool» ni «bassin», et d'utiliser «Lot» en français et «Batch» en anglais. Merci à tous pour vos interventions!

Comment: Il ne faut pas confondre les deux sens de pool en anglais. pool, piscine ou bassin, et pool qui veut dire (re)groupement des éléments. Je n'ai jamais vu ni entendu "un bassin de personnés qualifiées. Pour moi, il s'agit d'une grosse erreur,...Et on finance, on parle de pool d'investisseurs; aussi un pool dans le domaine juridique.

Comment: Bien d'accord sur le fait ne pas faire bêtement du mot-à-mot lorsqu'on traduit, mais les traductions que je trouve, notamment sur le site de l'OQLF (https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/) ne me donne pas des traductions que je trouve adéquates: consortium, équipe, etc. quel terme utiliseriez-vous à la place de bassin? Dîtes-vous que pool serait acceptable en français lorsqu'on parle d'un regroupement?

Comment: Is your context change point analysis?

Comment: Selon vos propres mots: le contexte d'un lot de changements devant être regroupés pour être appliqués ensemble.=groupement ou regroupement, Lorsqu'on met des éléments dans un pool en anglais, on les regroupe ou on les groupe. pool pour des biens, oui.

Comment: Groupement me semble aussi le mieux si on ne veut pas employer [pool](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/pool). Groupement ou mise en commun semblent  les plus appropriés parmi les termes proposés par [FranceTerme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=pool&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search)

Comment: I see "pool of changes" in a computing context via Google, but it's not that common. Is that the term  you have in English?

Comment: To be honest, I have in French «Sélection d'un pool» with no translation in English, Since we're about to launch, we are currently reviewing all labels on buttons and links. The dev team is based in Montreal and the software is meant to be used in North America primarily.

Comment: Pas d'opinion sur la traduction (cela depend énormément du public visé) mais il est amusant de constater que l'anglais nous a pris la *poule* http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?15;s=2974698165;r=1;nat=;sol=10; pour la renvoyer sous forme de *pool*... https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pool

Comment: NB: I thought you were asking about the French. Next time, **please be clearer about your source and target languages**. Thanks.

Comment: @Lambie Sorry you got confused. I was indeed looking for a French translation of the word. But after reading some comments, I realized that in my use case, the word «pool», which you hear sometimes in spoken french canadian (hence the label «Sélection d'un pool»), was maybe not the best word  to describe what we are trying to achieve.  So looking for the right word in french lead us to reassess the use of «pool» in English and we chose to change it.

Comment: Thanks for responding, much appreciated. The fact is that in English a pool of changes seem to have limited uses (occurrence-wise). Batch of changes is much better, and yes, for my money that is in un lot de changements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Même si *bassin (de personnes qualifiées)* est parfaitement usuel pour moi (Québec), tel qu'on le trouve sur le [site](https://www.scc-csc.ca/empl/lc-aj-fra.aspx) de la Cour suprême du Canada, et sur [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_b&page=9i8rQD5od-Zw.html#zz9i8rQD5od-Zw), et donc parfaitement correct et en usage (on note au passage le synonyme *réservoir*), ça ne signifie pas nécessairement qu'il convienne ici. Donc non. D'ailleurs, je ne sais pas si on a besoin d'un terme particulier pour décrire ce dont il s'agit.

Pour ne pas répéter ce qui a déjà été dit, j'ajouterais *masse/bloc/paquet/grappe/éventail* de changements. Mais selon moi la difficulté est de trop penser avec les références de la langue anglaise, et ce qui me vient à l'esprit c'est surtout ***série** de changements* à appliquer à telle date, la [*série*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/s%C3%A9rie) valant pour l'ensemble d'objets de même nature, ici des changements de prix. Hormis les excellents synonymes évoqués [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49571/26366) c'est ce que je trouve le plus usuel.

Comment: Série en anglais, c'est series.

Comment: Merci pour la suggestion. Le logiciel est développé au Québec et sera utilisé principalement en Amérique du Nord, en effet. Mais si «série» semble logique à priori, le terme n'illustre pas le concept de groupement et je vois mal l'équivalence entre pool et série lorsqu'on passe d'une langue à l'autre...

Comment: @Brac Bienvenu, je comprends les réserves. Mais justement, on a _lot_ (excellent) et _groupement_, _ensemble_. On a même _collection_, _liste_ voire _pile_ (stack), _tampon_, _banque_. Les objets ds. le _pool_ perdent-ils leur individualité, comme +1-4+2 = -1 est appliqué, ou séquentiel ? Je ne peux pas comprendre pourquoi _pool_ est utile. _Jeu_ est bien et comme on est en contexte du logiciel ok mais perso. ça me rappelle des outils, jeu de _wrench_, de clés etc. En fait _série_ signifie un ensemble et donc réfère au concept. _Groupe_ et _ensemble_ c'est les maths et ça parle à mon avis.

Comment: S'agit-il de _traitements par lot_ de changements soumis par des utilisateurs ? Je suis pas informaticien. Mais je peux m'imaginer dire _j'envoye ça dans le lot des changements à appliquer_. Ouais j'aime bien ça.

Comment: Très intéressants commentaires, avec «Pile» et «Tampon» qui réfère au concept qu'on avance. Mais l'utilisateur lambda non-technique va-t-il s'y retrouver davantage? Nous avons décidé de suivre vos dernières recommandations de ne pas aller avec «pool» ni «bassin», et d'utiliser «Lot» en français (qu'on retrouve dans ma question et dans le réponse de @jiliagre) et «Batch» en anglais. Exit le pool!

Comment: Juste une petite [saucette](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/saucette) comme on dit haha. On avait un problème qui sortait un peu du cadre de la langue et j'ai trouvé ça passablement difficile, avec en trame de fond pour moi la question de savoir quelles abstractions ancrées dans un lexique plus ou moins ésotérique doivent être présentées à l'utilisateur et pourquoi. Moi ce qui m'intéresse c'est de comprendre si le locuteur anglophone « voit » le contenant ou le liquide dedans et des choses qui s'y fondent ou si c'est aussi mathématique qu'ensemble, groupe. Pourquoi il choisit pool ou batch etc.

Comment: @Brac Peut-être la [perspective](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60218923#60218923) des locuteurs anglophones pour compléter...

Answer (score 5):

Tout dépend des personnes à qui est destinée l'application et sa documentation. S'il s'agit de Canadiens francophones, « bassin » est peut-être correct, étant une traduction du mot *pool* anglais que l'on peut rencontrer, par exemple, dans le principal quotidien québécois :

> *« Quand on a fait les tests avec un bassin de petites entreprises, on a vu que ça ne passait pas », admet M. Le Roux.* La Presse, 2014

S'il s'agit de francophones européens, « bassin » ne sera pas immédiatement compris et souvent pas compris du tout. Le mot *pool* pourra dans ce cas être conservé en français puisqu'il est bien établi avec ce sens, spécialement dans un contexte informatique.

Si on veut éviter « pool » et « bassin », on peut choisir suivant le cas « lot », « jeu », « groupe », « groupement », « ensemble », etc.

Une petite recherche étymologique apprend des choses intéressantes. Il existe deux mots *pool* en anglais, le premier est d'origine germanique et correspond à bassin, retenue d'eau, mare, etc. On le connaît bien avec *swimming-pool*.

Le deuxième mot est d'origine française et dérive du deuxième sens de « [poule](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poule) » en français : *quantité d'argent ou de jeton qui résulte de la mise de chacun des joueurs et qui appartient à celui qui gagne le coup* (1665), aujourd'hui couramment utilisé dans un contexte sportif (ex: *Coupe du monde 2022 : Le tirage au sort des poules prévu le 1er avril*, [RTBF](https://www.rtbf.be/article/coupe-du-monde-2022-le-tirage-au-sort-des-poules-prevu-le-1er-avril-10864782?id=10864782))

Il est donc dommage qu'on ait pas simplement retraduit *pool* par « poule »...

Comment: Bassin pourrait être compris en France, mais ça désigne un territoire, une zone (comme quand on parle de [bassin d'emploi](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bassin_d%27emploi)) plutôt qu'un réservoir/ *pool* de quelque chose.

Comment: @XouDo Oui, et c'est aussi le sens le plus courant au Québec. La question porte je pense sur des expressions comme *connection pool* ou *thread pool* que l'on traduit en général en France par *un pool de connexions* ou "un pool de threads" et que l'on ne peut pas le rendre par "un bassin de connexions/threads" et encore moins pas "un bassin de fils/brins".

Comment: Entre autres traduction possible pour pool, linguee propose "vivier" qui semble tout à fait couvrir ce sens (réserve d'élément prêt à servir), et qui est déjà parfois utilisé pour des candidats par exemple.

Comment: @XouDo Oui, vivier n'est pas mal, un bassin d'élevage. On pourrait même imaginer un *vivier de poules mouillées* ;-)

Comment: Je ne sais pas pour vous, ni pour Linguee, mais vivier me fait vraiment penser aux homards....

Comment: @Brac Oui, c'est pour ça que les poules qu'on y met se mouillent... ;-)

Comment: Miam, eurêka ! La marmite à changements ``)

Comment: @jlliagre Bon point concernant l'étymologie. Je retiens que «bassin» peut s'utiliser au Canada français pour un bon nombre de contextes, mais quelques interventions, dont la vôtre, nous ont amenés à remettre en question le mot «pool» en anglais. Merci!

Answer (score 0):

Dans le cadre d'un logiciel, j'ai pour ma part conservé le mot "pool" parce qu'il est mieux compris des utilisateurs (en l'espèce, un "pool de supports de stockage") et fait partie de la terminologie ordinaire dans le domaine. Mais pour des dates, des changements, ce ne serait clairement pas mon choix (je préfère comme précédemment cité par d'autres *jeu* ou autre synonyme) mais ça reste une question de préférence.

Comment: «Pool» ne fait pas l'unanimité chez les francophones du Québec selon ce que je me rends compte. Nos tests utilisateurs nous ont démontré que si quelques personnes comprennent la signification au sens où on l'entend, la plupart restent confus devant ce mot (ils pensent à piscine ou à pool de hockey par exemple). Nous avons décidé de retirer ce mot dans le but d'être le plus intuitif. En effet, «jeu» est un bon candidat.